# Decoding HTML Entities to Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

Well, Since yesterday I'm having trouble with this. I need to save some text into a ".txt" file, the problem is that there are html entities in the text I'm trying to save.

So I imported HTMLPaser in my code:

```
import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
print h.unescape(text) // right?
```

the thing is that this works when you try to print the result, but i'm trying to return this to a function of mine which actually saves the text to the file. So, when I'm trying to save the file, the system says:

```
exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've been reading about this but I cannot conclude anything, I tried BeautifulSoup, I tried functions from famous pythonists and none worked. Can you help me with this?  I need to save the text in the file as unicode and by unicode I understand it will save characters like: **á**, right?

Comment: Can you show us the code that's writing the file? It sounds like the problem is really with writing the file rather than reading the html (since you say that that's working when you test it with print/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Save Unicode character to a file" is a different question from *"Decoding HTML Entities to Unicode"*. Your code (`h.unescape(text)`) already decodes the html text correctly.

The exception is due to `print unicode_text` e.g.:

```
print u"\N{EURO SIGN}"
```

should produce a similar error.

If you're saving to a file by redirecting the output of the python script e.g.:

```
$ python -m your_module >output.txt #XXX raises an error for non-ascii data
```

then define `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` envvar (to save using utf-8 encoding):

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -m your_module >output.txt
```

If you want to save to a file directly in your Python code, use `io` module:

```
import io

with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(h.unescape(text))
```